# API for Google Newsstand

Tags: api, google-play

Google Play has Newsstand application (not available everywhere) - https://play.google.com/store/newsstand. It replaces older Currents application. It displays news/articles from many different websites/magazines/feeds.

Does any, official or unofficial, API exist, that would let me use those sources in my own application?

Answer (score 1):

As far as official APIs go, unfortunately Google doesn't provide anything if their [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is any indication. Google News [used to have an API](https://developers.google.com/news-search/?csw=1), but it was deprecated in 2011.

The closest thing to what I think you're looking for, assuming you want to stick with Google, would be the RSS output from Google News. You can pass an optional query parameter to search for specific topics. For example:

```
https://news.google.com/news?q=obama&output=rss
```

If you're looking for a similar service to Play Newsstand that offers an API, check out these:

- Some individual sources offer APIs, such as the [NYTimes](http://developer.nytimes.com/) and [USA Today](http://developer.usatoday.com)
- Feedly has a [nice-looking API](https://developer.feedly.com/), although I have never used it personally.

Good luck with your search!